# Advanced Variables in button: Name, City, State

Tags: button, paypal, customization

I can't seem to locate a list of what PayPal can use in the "Advanced Variables" section when editing a PayPal button.

Older posts here point to a page that does not refer to Advanced Variables.

I don't need or want the customer shipping address (we are holding tickets at the door, we don't want them to think we're shipping them), but I do need their First & Last name, and their City and State.

I did find a place to require a phone number (under website settings), separate from the button.  Though I'm not sure if that's the correct place for that.

I've read that it's a bad idea to edit the PayPal form directly in the html on my site, that it's safer to do it within PayPal, but I can't find instructions.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the developer guide on the HTML variables for payment buttons:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/ButtonManagerHTMLVariables/